# Setting Selected Value Mat-Select

Tags: angular, angular-material

My requirement is to show extraInfo in Mat Option. But when user selects any of the option I need not show the extra info once selected. To achieve this I am using .

But while trying to set value after form creation I am not able to do so.

My Code Below:

HTML---

```
<form [formGroup]="issueFieldsForm">

<mat-form-field appearance="fill" >
  <mat-label> Select</mat-label>
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="onchange($event)" formControlName="testDropDown">
    <mat-select-trigger >{{selected}}</mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
     
      {{food.viewValue}}
      <span>test</span>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

</form>
```

component.ts:

```
export class SelectOverviewExample implements OnInit{

  public selected: any;
  public issueFieldsForm: FormGroup;

  foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'},
  ];

  public onchange(event:any){
    console.log(event);
    this.selected = this.foods.filter((obj)=> obj.value == event.value)[0].viewValue;
    console.log(this.selected)
  }
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.issueFieldsForm = new FormGroup<any | any>({testDropDown : new FormControl(null)})      
      this.issueFieldsForm.controls.testDropDown.setValue('tacos-2');
    }
}
```

One way is to filter the value and set by updating selected value. But I cannot do it. Because my dropdown is custom component itself. There I cannot pass the value.

Stackblitz for the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwpwrm?file=src/app/select-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

Create a display function that will get the viewValue based on the selection inside your component something like

```
displayFunc(selectedVal:any){
    let food=this.foods.find(f=> f.value==selectedVal);
    return food?.viewValue;
  }
```

Then call this function inside mat select trigger

```
 <mat-select (selectionChange)="onchange($event)" formControlName="testDropDown" #select>
    <mat-select-trigger >{{displayFunc(select.value)}}</mat-select-trigger>
```

You can get the selected value using hash on mat select as well.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwpwrm-z5eivf?file=src/app/select-overview-example.html)

Comment: this doesnot works

Comment: @Amit you can check the demo link when you say this doesnot works did you mean in some specific case?

Comment: Yes for my case #select doesnot have value

Comment: @Amit add a stackblitz for that problem

Comment: this doesnot work for angular v7

Answer (score -1):

Replace this line -

```
<mat-select-trigger >{{selected}}</mat-select-trigger>
```

with this -

```
<mat-option></mat-option>
```

Result -

[image: ma-select-default-value]

Comment: op want to display a different value after selection so only he use mat select trigger it will work they way you did even if you  remove the mat select trigger and put nothing in place